# Net::HTTP - How can I open a link with adress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, faye, net-http

I need to open this link with Net::HTTP:

```
"http://localhost:9292/something"
```

Terminal:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("http://localhost",9292)
=> #<Net::HTTP http://localhost:9292 open=false>
```

How can I open this link, any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Define "open".

Comment: Also, what is wrong with the plethora of examples in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)?

Comment: I need to go to this link: "http://localhost:9292/login". With Net::HTTP I can go only to "http://localhost:9292". How can I go to ".../login"?

Comment: What do you want to go to the link (obviously **you** can't go. Do you want to fetch the data and put it in a ruby string? Do you want to send the browser there? Something else?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'open-uri'
contents = open('http://localhost:9292/login') {|f| f.read }
```

Or with `Net::HTTP`:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://localhost:9292/login')
contents = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```